# System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.", что делать?

Tags: c#

Задача: составить программу, которая определяет одинаковые и стоящие рядом числа в текстбоксах и подкрашивает их цветом. Массив текстбоксов создан, работает, числами заполняется. Когда я ставлю задачу выделить цветом какое-то конкретное число из текстбоксов, то всё работает. Но когда ставлю сравнение между двумя текстбоксами, а не текстбоксом и числом, выбивает ошибку из заголовка. 
Так оно выглядит при сравнении с числом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Соответственно, подсвечиваться должны только 3 блока снизу слева, тк там они стоят рядом. И, естественно, должно работать с любым числом. То есть, брать каждый бокс(его значение) и сравнивать с окружающими боксами на соответствие. Так же догадываюсь, что нужно как-то ограничить сравнение в таких местах, как в самом первом боксе со значениями -1 по иску и игреку, но так же не догоняю как это сделать. Буду признателен за любую помощь.

Код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace tmp_9
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        Button b1 = new Button();
        TextBox[,] a;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int i, j, u, k, f;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Controls.Add(b1);
        b1.Click += b1_click;
        b1.SetBounds(10, 10, 55, 20);
    }

    private void b1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        u = 10; k = 10;
        a = new TextBox[u, k];

        for (i=0; i<u; i++)
        {
            f = i + 1;
            for (j=0; j<k; j++)
            {
                a[i, j] = new TextBox();
                Controls.Add(a[i, j]);
                a[i, j].SetBounds(100 + i * 40, 100 + j * 20, 40, 40);
                a[i, j].Text = "" + rnd.Next(5, 20);

                if (a[i, j].Text == "5") //a[i + 1, j].Text) //вот тут, собсна, 
//пример в закомментированом пространстве того, как я пытаюсь реализовать задумку
                {
                    a[i, j].BackColor = Color.Red;
                    //a[i + 1, j].BackColor = Color.Red;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.

Разделите операции заполнения массива и сравнения соседних элементов. Вы пытаетесь сравнить текущий (только что созданный) элемент и элемент, который Вы еще не создали.

2.

```
if (a[i, j].Text == a[i + 1, j].Text)
```

Чему будет равен первый индекс во втором операнде, когда `i` равно `u - 1`?

Comment: U, в моем понимании, как и k, отвечает просто за размерность массива. Что-то я не совсем понимаю, почему 'i' должен равняться 'u - 1'

Comment: @ДенисКлименко У Вас две ошибки. Они идут в ответе под номерами 1. и 2. Давайте сосредоточимся на первой. Вам понятно, в чем там дело?

Comment: С первой вроде да, я убрал фрагмент со сравнением элементов за пределы цикла с созданием массива, поставил его сразу после этого самого цикла. Но надо поместить этот фрагмент внутрь подобного цикла, чтобы он проходил через все текстбоксы, я так понимаю

Comment: @ДенисКлименко Надо написать еще один двойной цикл, после двойного цикла, в котором создаются текстбоксы.

Comment: Сделал идентичный цикл  
  `for (i = 0; i < u; i++)
            {          
                for (j = 0; j < k; j++)
                {
                    if (a[i, j].Text == a[i, j+1].Text)
                    {
                        a[i, j].BackColor = Color.Red;
                        a[i, j+1].BackColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                }
            }`

Ps. Какое ужасное форматирование тут в комменте

Comment: @ДенисКлименко Молодец. Ошибку "Index out of range" получили?

Comment: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: "Индекс находился вне границ массива."
Полагаю, что это оно. Да, получил. И думаю, что это потому, что в определенных координатах действительно нарушаются границы массива. Как, например, в элементе 10 и 10, если я буду там сравнивать со следующим элементом(10+1), которого нет. Но не понимаю, как поправить это

Comment: @ДенисКлименко Очень хорошо. Это ошибка номер два. Напишите в цикле сравнения значений: `for (j = 0; j < k - 1; j++)`.

Comment: Поставил, работает по вертикали. Если я правильно понял, то мы исключаем для данного сравнения последний элемент?

Comment: @ДенисКлименко Да, последний элемент в строке. С чем бы Вы хотели сравнить последний элемент? Ведь у него нет следующего.